# JavaScript get element from event trigger

Tags: javascript, html, web

I'm currently trying to programm my first Website.
Therefore I want to get all Elements with a certain class an give them all the same EventListeners.
I did that like this:

```
const certs = document.getElementsByClassName("certificate");

for (var i = 0; i < certs.length; i++) {
    certs[i].addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOver());
    certs[i].addEventListener("mouseout", mouseOut());
}

function mouseOver() {
    this.querySelector(".overlay").classList.add("active");
}

function mouseOut() {
    this.querySelector(".overlay").classList.remove("active");
}
```

My Problem is, "this" doesnt seem to be the element which is triggering the mouseOver event.
I also tried puting "this" as a parameter like here:

```
const certs = document.getElementsByClassName("certificate");

for (var i = 0; i < certs.length; i++) {
    certs[i].addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOver(this));
    certs[i].addEventListener("mouseout", mouseOut(this));
}

function mouseOver(elem) {
    elem.querySelector(".overlay").classList.add("active");
}

function mouseOut(elem) {
    elem.querySelector(".overlay").classList.remove("active");
}
```

Both ways didnt work and know I am stuck in a way...
Is there a way to do this?
How can I use the exact element triggering the event?

(I dont want to give every element a unique ID to make it reusable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument of `addEventListener` is a function. Right now, you're calling the function immediately, which returns `undefined`, so whenever you move your mouse over or out it attempts to run `undefined`. Pass just the function variable itself, `addEventListener` will handle calling the function later.

`addEventListener` calls the callback function with an `Event` object, which has the property `target` which is how you get your element.

```js
const certs = document.getElementsByClassName("certificate");

for (var i = 0; i < certs.length; i++) {
    certs[i].addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOver);
    certs[i].addEventListener("mouseout", mouseOut);
}

function mouseOver(event) {
    event.target.querySelector(".overlay").classList.add("active");
}

function mouseOut(event) {
    event.target.querySelector(".overlay").classList.remove("active");
}
```